# Faster calculation of squared norm in Cython

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, numpy, cython

I would like to calculate squared norms, which can be written as
[image]

W is a matrix and has V rows. u is a vector. I have two numpy objects W and u.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as npr
V = 10
W = npr.normal(size=(V, 3))
u = npr.normal(size=(1,3))
```

If I calculate row by row, I can do like this:

```
res = np.zeros(V)
for v in range(V):
    res[v] = (W[v] - u).dot((W[v] - u).transpose())
```

But it could be slow once V gets large (say 5000) and  I need to recalculate it again and again.
So I tried matrix multiplication, but it did not work out because it is not a row by row multiplication.

```
((W - u).transpose()).dot(W - u)
```

How can I calculate the squared norm fast in Numpy?

I am planning to use Cython, so could row by row multiplication in loop be faster than Numpy? I learned that Cython has [parallelization](http://nealhughes.net/parallelcomp2/), but it seems Cython can not parallelize `for loop` if I use Numpy object inside (Added on 20/Nov: probably I can not use Python object inside the `prange` but I can use Numpy object).

Comment: you can also use `np.linalg.norm(W-u)`

Comment: Did you add a `cdef int v` typing to your looping variable? If not, that could cause some slowdown. But you are right about parallelization in cython; if you touch any python objects within your loop, you cannot use OpenMP functions like `prange`. Anyways it looks like you already got a smarter python solution!

Comment: @CodeSurgeon Above, I only showed Python version for easy replication, but I will appropriately define variables in Cython!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Approach #1

You can leverage the fast BLAS based [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) right with NumPy without any looping, like so -

```
res = (W**2).sum(1) + (u**2).sum(1) -2*W.dot(u.ravel())
```

Bringing in [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) to get the row-wise summations of `W` and `np.inner` for those of `u` -

```
res = np.einsum('ij,ij->i',W,W) + np.inner(u,u).ravel() -2*W.dot(u.ravel())
```

**Explanation on the method**

With `(W[v] - u).dot((W[v] - u)` at each iteration, we are doing inner dot product. Since, we are doing this for all rows of `W`, that translates to `((W - u)**2).sum(1)` upon leveraging broadcasting.

Now,

```
(Xik-Yjk)**2 = Xik**2 + Yjk**2 - 2*Xik*Yjk
```

Hence,

```
sum_k((Xik-Yjk)**2) = sum_k(Xik**2) + sum_k(Yjk**2) - 2*sum_k(Xik*Yjk)
```

The last term on RHS is basically matrix-multiplication, which we are leveraging with `np.dot`.

#### Approach #2

Alternatively, using more of `np.einsum`, it would be like so -

```
d = W -u
res = np.einsum('ij,ij->i',d,d)
```

Comment: If I use np.dot() in Cython, does it become slower than using it in pure Python?

Comment: @user2978524 If you can use `np.dot` right here in NumPy, I don't think you would see any benefit over it going to cython.

Comment: I see, you are right. Could you tell me how you come up with the first answer (the one with np.dot)? I always have hard time with numpy, and I am not sure why your answer gives what I want, which makes me stuck at the same issue in the future. Do you know any useful reference?

Comment: @user2978524 Added.